# python is not running in the same cmd window

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, pip

I have installed python 3. When I want to use pip it opens a new window and the messages and logs disappear immediately by closing that cmd window, but in some days ago when i used pip it open that in the same window. I have tried and search many ways but the problem is still remaining. what should I do?

Comment: look for the logs and google for the error messages...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done the problem was for AVG PC tuneup. this program was closing python. so python is was opening in new window. I simply removed this program. I tried disable Live optimization. But not worked.